# Responding to a click on a Vue element programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Essentially, I want my Vue instance to respond to a click on an uploaded thumbnail.

I'm using the [FineUploader Vue package](https://github.com/FineUploader/vue-fineuploader/tree/v2) with the template layout per the docs (see end of the question). Upon uploading an image, a tree like this is outputted:

```
<Root>
   <Gallery>
      <Thumbnail>
    </Gallery>
</Root>
```

Coming from a jQuery background I really have no idea about the 'correct' way to go about this given that the Thumbnail Template is defined by the package already, and so I'm not creating my own Thumbnail template. I know that I can access elements like this:

`let thumb = this.$el.querySelector('.vue-fine-uploader-thumbnail');`

And perhaps a listener

```
 thumb.addEventListener('click', function() {
       alert('I got clicked');
   });
```

But dealing with the Vue instance being re-rendered etc. I'm not familiar with.

Vue Template:

```
<template>
  <Gallery :uploader="uploader" />
</template>

<script>
  import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers'
  import Gallery from 'vue-fineuploader/gallery'

  export default {
    components: {
      Gallery
    },
    data () {
      const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
        options: {/*snip*/}
      })

      return {
        uploader
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think an @click handler in <Gallery> will be activated by the child <thumbnail>.

Comment: @Andrew1325 I couldn't get that to work. Perhaps the Gallery Template in the package prevents it from working.

Comment: Yeah because Gallery is a component you can maybe use an emit to trigger a $on call back. Like `<Gallery @click="$emit(eventName)">` then in created have `this.$on(eventName, callback)`. See [https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on]

Comment: You might be able to capture the click with `@click.native` to get the root element click of your `Gallery` component. This might break though if the library decides to change the structure of the gallery component. With questions like this it is useful to provide a codesandbox or fiddle so people can help better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to respond to click events you add the `v-on:click` (or it's short form: `@click`) to whatever tag you want.

If you have elements that are nested that respond to the click event you might experience that a click on a child triggers a parents click event. To prevent this you add `@click.stop` instead, so that it doesn't trigger the parents click.

So you would have something along the lines of:

```
<Gallery @click="myFunction" />
```